# How to make template function specialization for vector and list types

Tags: c++

I tried to implement template function specialization. You can run my tiny code in [this](https://godbolt.org/g/o29oNy) fiddle. You can also see it below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>


template <typename T>
struct is_vector {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T>> {
    static const bool value = true;
    using type = std::vector<T>;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_list {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_list<std::list<T>> {
    static const bool value = true;
    using type = std::list<T>;
};


template<typename T, class = typename std::enable_if<is_list<T>::value>::type>
void foo(T t) {
    std::cout << "is list" << std::endl;
}

/*
template<typename T, class = typename std::enable_if<is_vector<T>::value>::type>
void foo(T t) {
    std::cout << "is vector" << std::endl;
}
*/
//The above code will cause an error, if we uncomment it

int main()
{

    foo(std::list<int>{});    

    return 0;
}
```

In this code, I have several lines commented:

```
template<typename T, class = typename std::enable_if<is_vector<T>::value>::type>
void foo(T t) {
    std::cout << "is vector" << std::endl;
}
```

If I uncomment it, I get "redifinition" error. I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this instead.

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<is_list<T>::value>::type foo(T t) {
    std::cout << "is list" << std::endl;
}


template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<is_vector<T>::value>::type foo(T t) {
    std::cout << "is vector" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> If I uncomment it, I get "redifinition" error. I'm not sure how to fix it.

The reason is quite simple: default values for template type arguments are not a part of a function signature. It means that you have the same template defined two times.

You might move *SFINAE* part in to the function return type, as it is suggested by other answers, or change the code to:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_list<T>::value, int> = 0>
void foo(T t) {
    std::cout << "is list" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_vector<T>::value, int> = 1>
void foo(T t) {
    std::cout << "is vector" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but you could just check if either list or vector is a matching type:

```
template<typename T, class = typename std::enable_if<is_list<T>::value || is_vector<T>::value>::type>
void foo(T t) {
    std::cout << "is list" << std::endl;
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://godbolt.org/g/oD3o9q

Update (for C++14):

```
template<typename T, class = std::enable_if_t<is_list<T>::value || is_vector<T>::value>>
void foo(T t) {
    std::cout << "is list" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Pro tip: `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` -> `std::enable_if_t<...>`.

Comment: I need two different implementations for vector and for list type.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks. Updated my "answer"